# visiting visa for my mother to come to the uk

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I leave in the uk with my husband and I just had a baby.  I want my mum to come viait for 3 month. my question is; does my mother need to submit any document from her like bank statement.  she does not work she is just a petty trade just to keep busy.

Comment: Given the family ties in the UK, and that she can leave her life in her home country for an extended period, your mother will also need to demonstrate strong ties to her home country. If she doesn't she may be refused because the IO believes she will overstay. This is even more important if you intend to sponsor her.